# List view row not selectable

Tags: android, listview, select

I have list view with a text, i have a edit button onclick on that i can select and deselect the list items, its working fine in Nexus One,Kindle but its not working on Samusng S3 and Galaxy grand.

Here is my code:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(activity);
    listView.setId(LIST_VIEW_ID);   
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x99000000));
    listView.setDividerHeight(1);
    listView.setSelector(R.drawable.selector);
```

in getView():

```
if (isEditButtonPressed) {
        if (selectedItems.contains(values[position])) {
            convertView.setSelected(true);
            convertView.setPressed(true);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7177"));
        } else {
            convertView.setSelected(false);
            convertView.setPressed(false);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        }
```

**EDIT**

Note : here i can select multiple list items.

Comment: check with `state_active`

Comment: @deadfish  where ? how to set it ?

Comment: Your question is not clear... Can you explain to me clearly

Comment: if you are using custom slector in xml -> define `state_activated` and use the same drawable as it was in pressed, if you are using only code try use `.setActivated(true)`

Comment: .setActivated(true) to which one to the converView or list view ?

Comment: @Goofy current view / converView

Comment: @deadfish its in api 11 and i cant use that

Comment: How many list items you have in your list view?

Comment: @saa its dynamic, how it is related to no of items ?

Comment: Ok.. what is convertView?

Comment: @saa hmmm, its how we inflate the xml- which has a text view defined in it

Comment: try like this convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView).setSelected(true);

Comment: Please post your full getView() method code.. It may helpful to debug this problem